# detect conflict of store_X options in OptionParser

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, optparse

Given the following code using optparse:

```
from optparse import OptionParser
opt = OptionParser(version='%prog alfa')
opt.add_option('-a', action='store_true', dest='test')
opt.add_option('-b', action='store_false', dest='test')
opt.set_defaults(test=None)

options, args = opt.parse_args()
print options.test
```

The code works fine, but it allows executions with both `-a` and `-b` and the end result depends on the last option specified. Notice that the same `test` variable is used to indicate that options `-a` and `-b` were used.

## Constraints:

- I can not use `argparse` as the code needs to work with python versions older than 2.4
- I really need the `options.test` variable to be able to have all three values of `None`, `True` and `False`

## Question:

**How do I detect that both options were used?**

I want to raise an error (using `opt.error`) when both options are present... or at least show the user some kind of warning.